# Adding columns in Spark dataframe based on rules

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df, which contains below data:

```
**customers**   **product**   **Val_id**
     1               A            1
     2               B            X
     3               C               
     4               D            Z
```

i have been provided 2 rules, which are as below:

```
**rule_id**   **rule_name**  **product value**  **priority**
   123              ABC             A,B               1
   456              DEF             A,B,D             2
```

Requirement is to apply these rules on dataframe df in priority order, customers who have passed rule 1, should not be considered for rule 2 and in final dataframe add two more columns rule_id and rule_name, i have written below code to achieve it:

```
val rule_name = when(col("product").isin("A","B"), "ABC").otherwise(when(col("product").isin("A","B","D"), "DEF").otherwise(""))
val rule_id = when(col("product").isin("A","B"), "123").otherwise(when(col("product").isin("A","B","D"), "456").otherwise(""))
val df1 = df_customers.withColumn("rule_name" , rule_name).withColumn("rule_id" , rule_id)
df1.show()
```

Final output looks like below:

```
**customers**   **product**   **Val_id**  **rule_name**  **rule_id**
     1               A            1           ABC            123
     2               B            X           ABC            123
     3               C               
     4               D            Z           DEF            456
```

Is there any better way to achieve it, adding both columns by just going though entire dataset once instead of going through entire dataset twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question : Is there any better way to achieve it, adding both columns
>   by just going though entire dataset once instead of going through
>   entire dataset twice?

***Answer*** : you  can have a Map return type in scala...

> Limitation : This udf if you are using with With Column for example
>   column name is `ruleIDandRuleName` then you can use a single fuction
>   with Map data type or any acceptable data type of spark sql column.
>   Other wise you cant use the below mentioned approach

shown in the below example snippet

```
      def ruleNameAndruleId = udf((product : String) => {  
 if(Seq("A", "B").contains(product)) Map("ruleName"->"ABC","ruleId"->"123")   
    else if(Seq("A", "B", "D").contains(product)) (Map("ruleName"->"DEF","ruleId"->"456")   
    else (Map("ruleName"->"","ruleId"->"") })
```

caller will be

```
df.withColumn("ruleIDandRuleName",ruleNameAndruleId(product here) ) // ruleNameAndruleId  will return a map containing rulename and rule id
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your solution would be to use `udf` functions. Its almost similar to `when` function as both required `serialization` and `deserialization`. Its upto you to test which is faster and efficient.

```
def rule_name = udf((product : String) => {
  if(Seq("A", "B").contains(product)) "ABC"
  else if(Seq("A", "B", "D").contains(product)) "DEF"
  else ""
})

def rule_id = udf((product : String) => {
  if(Seq("A", "B").contains(product)) "123"
  else if(Seq("A", "B", "D").contains(product)) "456"
  else ""
})

val df1 = df_customers.withColumn("rule_name" , rule_name(col("product"))).withColumn("rule_id" , rule_id(col("product")))
df1.show()
```

Comment: A `udf` function will return only one value at a time which will be transformed into column by `withColumn` function. You can return combined value from `udf` but you will have to `split` the combined value using two `withColumn` function. So I suggest you to use two separate `udf`s instead of one. If you have more columns to be generated with new rules then you can do so by converting the `dataframe` to `rdd` and generate all necessary columns on one go and convert to `dataframe` again. But for the current scenario using two `udf`s is the right solution :)